# Display first 3 line from large paragraph from php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and MySQL to get data from database. I have one description field in database. In description field contains large para.

For example: (In database description field contain this para)

> The ‘Fox and the Grapes’ is often cited as an example for cognitive dissonance: the discomfort people experience when their beliefs/actions are at odds with other beliefs/actions. In the story, the fox sees some grapes on a vine and wants to eat them. He tries to jump up, but cannot reach them because they are too high. When he realizes he will not be able to eat any grapes, the fox becomes disdainful; he tells himself that those grapes were sour and not worthy of desire anyway.

Now I want only first three line from this para like that

> The ‘Fox and the Grapes’ is often cited as an example for cognitive dissonance: the discomfort people experience when their beliefs/actions are at odds with other beliefs/actions.

Comment: Lines will be difficult as it depends on where you display the text. How about taking the first 200 chars?

Comment: use wordwrap or mb_substr fucntions in php. But it will be character specific  not line specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of first three line, you can go with first `100` or `200` characters what ever fulfill you requirements and show `...` or `more` button to get the entire text. For this you have to take the first 100 or 200 characters of the entire text and after that show `...` or `more` button.

For taking the first 100 characters of a string make sure you don't break a word like:

```
$pos=strpos($content, ' ', 200);
echo substr($content,0,$pos );
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8abe0718b06d138729b2cae0ed61817638d9778)

Comment: I applied your solution but how to display ... @Mayank Pandeyz

Comment: Is this UTF-8 aware?

Comment: No also when I fetch contain from database in html side there will be display like that   Series�  how to solve this problem sir. Can you help me ?  @tadman

Comment: Sir, Please suggest how to set ... I fetch 200 characters from database but how to showing ... @MayankPandeyz

Comment: Check this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8abe0718b06d138729b2cae0ed61817638d9778

Comment: I already applied.. I want this type of output DEFEF EWTRWT AEGRT AET ETRT ETWRT ETY... @MayankPandeyz last three dots now you got it my point?

Comment: Try this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1fe79f26197dccac2502efdad7f4e20f2a2069f1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put the entire paragraph  in the webpage i.e: inside a div / p tag and use web designing skills to achieve your goal.

Putting a paragraph in a table is not appropriate if you apply normalisation. Apart from that the performance will be hampered in the long run.

If you still want to go ahead then parsing will help you.